# artifactory force update of remote repos

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have had a working artifactory for over a year now.  I have set up a virtual repo that has my local (company) artifacts,  along with the maven repo (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)  and a few others.

I have a working spring boot app,  and I am simply updating to the new 2x version  (Currently 2.0.0.M6)  my POM parent looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

When I try and do a mvn install -U  I get an error:

```
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.springframework.boot:myProject:[unknown-version]: 
Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.0.M6 in central (http://xxx/artifactory/myVirtualRepo/) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 9, column 12
```

Now when I change that back to my original version (1.5.7.RELEASE)  it works fine.

If I manually go and check my artifactory,  I do NOT see a 2.0.0.M6 version there.  So the error makes sense,  but how do I get my Artifactory to "update" or whatever,  the newer versions listed on maven central?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am not seeing the artifact you are looking for in Maven central :-)
According to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/, the artifact's latest version is 1.5.9

If you look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent, you can see that the 2.0.0-MX versions are only available on the springio-milestone mirror.

You probably need to add another remote repository that relies on http://repo.spring.io/milestone/, and add it to your virtual repository.

This should fix it.